# Swift NSStackView : Learn By Doing. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, 2d, appkit

How do I get my `NSStackView` to lay out my view one after the other ? My blue box is drawing on top of my red box.

```
import Cocoa

class TestView : NSView{
  override init() {
    super.init(frame: NSRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 100,height: 100))
  }

  required init(coder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    NSColor.redColor().setFill()
    NSBezierPath.fillRect(self.bounds)
  }
}

class TestView2 : NSView{
  override init() {
    super.init(frame: NSRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 100,height: 100))
  }

  required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    NSColor.blueColor().setFill()
    NSBezierPath.fillRect(self.bounds)
  }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

  @IBOutlet weak var searchFacetItems: SearchFacetSelectorView!
  @IBOutlet weak var searchFacetHeader: SearchFacetSelectorHeader!
  var content : NSStackView!
  let testView = TestView()
  let testView2 = TestView2()

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    content = NSStackView(frame: window.contentView.bounds)
        content.orientation = NSUserInterfaceLayoutOrientation.Vertical
        content.alignment = NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX

    content.addView(testView, inGravity: NSStackViewGravity.Center)
    content.addView(testView2, inGravity: NSStackViewGravity.Center)


    window.contentView = content!
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
  }


}
```

**learn by reading**

It's not appkit, but maybe i'll get some clues: [HOW TO USE UIVIEWS WITH AUTO LAYOUT PROGRAMMATICALLY](http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/)

[Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by adjusting the `NSRect` coordinates. Currently you've got both `NSRects` using the same exact coordinates:

```
NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
```

If you want the `NSView` horizontally (on the right) located next of the other:

```
NSRect(0, 0, 100, 100)    // TestView1
NSRect(100, 0, 100, 100)  // TestView2
```

vertically below:

```
NSRect(0, 0, 100, 100)    // TestView1
NSRect(0, -100, 100, 100) // TestView2
```

Comment: I have tried that before and it does work. But I am expecting the stack view to lay out the views it manages sensibly itself.

Answer (score 0):

The views don't have any constraints that describe their preferred sizes, such as `intrinsicContentSize`s or explicit constraints. And `NSStackView` only adds constraints that positions its stacked views relative to each other, not ones to size individual views.

Without them, their size in the stacking axis becomes ambiguous and will typically give all of the sizing to a single view. In your example, I'd guess that the blue box is not drawing on top of the red box, but just that the red box has a 0 height (and is stacked after the blue view).

Adding `NSButton`s to a stack view don't have this problem, as they do have a defined `intrinsicContentSize`.

Depending on what your views are -- do they have *intrinsic* sizes, or will they be defined by constraints to internal subviews -- you'll either want to override `intrinsicContentSize` or add those constraints that end up defining their heights.

---

*Edit:* Oh, and make sure `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `false` on the views you're adding to the stack view (it doesn't look like you are from the sample code). If not, you'll quickly run into trouble where the autoresizing constraints are trying to position the view and conflicting with constraints that the stack view adds.